# Scrolling in Chrome on Windows 7 is very slow?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, scrolling

I have Chrome 13.0.782.220 m version and Windows 7 Proffesional. The problem is that when I open random site in new tab and then continue to scroll in the current site, the scrolling starts to lag big time. I must wait to load completely the new tab, and then continue to use/read the same site. I tried Smooth Scrolling extension and nothing. I have these extensions installed:

1. Neat Bookmarks
2. Adblock
3. FlashBlock
4. After The Deadline
5. LastPass
6. Clip to Evernote
7. TabCloud
8. WOT

and this apps (apps running in the background):

1. Quick Note
2. Read Later Fast

My HP ProBook 4510s laptop specifications are:

- Processor :Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor T5870 (2.0 GHz , 2 MB L2 cache, 800 MHz FSB)
- Operating System :Genuine Windows Vista Home Basic 32
- Chipset :Mobile Intel PM45 Express Chipset
- System Memory : 3GBB (1 x 1024 MB + 1 x 2048 MB) DDR2 800 MHz ,Up to 8GB
- Hard Drive :320GB 5400RPM SATA HDD
- Display :15.6-inch diagonal LED-backlit HD anti-glare (1366 x 768 resolution)
- Graphics :ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 4330,512 MB dedicated video memory (1024 MB HyperMemory)
- Audio :High Definition Audio support
- Optical Drive :SATA DVD+/-RW SuperMulti DL LightScribe Drive
- ...

I noticed that in about:plugins there is two or more plugins like Flash (Flash installation  and built in Flash plugin in Chrome)...

So what is the problem here? I have no problem using Firefox (Aurora version), IE9 and Opera.
Is something to do with the extensions or the plugins? I'm thinking switching back to Firefox because of this :S :\

Comment: Try disabling all extensions - or load the page in incognito mode. If it's fine then you have a extension problem

Comment: @Sathya that's quite a good idea, I didn't think of that :D
 thanks

Comment: Post an answer if you find the errant extension. BTW - I'd recommend you not use Smooth Scroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errant extension appears to be LastPass.

I am on the same version of Chrome on Linux, and have been facing the slow, sluggish scrolling since LastPass's last update released a couple of days ago.

Disabling LastPass immediately fixes the slow scrolling issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention, LastPass will address this in our next release. -Bob from LastPass

Comment: This has been driving me nuts!

Comment: LastPass has fixed this problem in the latest release. Thanks to LastPass team for the quick response to the support ticket I raised with them!

Answer (score 1):

I've been having scrolling issues for a while, and it got much worse after the last Chrome update, on both of my machines. Disabling the WOT extension made the problem go away for me.